# How do I check if an argument(money amount) has only 2 decimal places?

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I am working on my first own money system. So far, except for one thing, everything is going great.

I currently can't find a solution to block from the 3rd decimal place of my argument if it is "0".

Example: `/pay (Player) (1.11000000000000...1)`

With `(!(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(args[1])).scale() > 2))`, every number except 0 is blocked from the 3rd decimal place on.

With `NumberFormat` the amounts are displayed correctly to all players, but in the database then the crooked amount is entered.

Do you have any idea how I can block this?

```
public class Command_Geld implements CommandExecutor {

    Api_Money moneyapi = new Api_Money();

    public boolean isDouble(String isDouble) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(isDouble);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;
           
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7/Bezahlen §8(§aSpieler§8) §8(§aBetrag§8)");
                player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Deine HardwareWallet: §a" + nf.format(moneyapi.getMoney(player.getUniqueId())) + " §7Satoshis");
                return false;
            } else {
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);

                if (args.length == 1) {
                    player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7/Bezahlen §8(§aSpieler§8) §8(§aBetrag§8)");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (isDouble(args[1])) {
                            if (Double.parseDouble(args[1]) >= 0.01) {
                                if (target != null) {
                                    if (target == player) {
                                        if (!(BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(args[1])).scale() > 2)) {
                                            moneyapi.removeMoney(player.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
                                            moneyapi.addMoney(target.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1]));

                                            player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Bezahlt: §a" + target.getName().toString() + "§8(§c-" + nf.format(Double.parseDouble(args[1])) + "§8)");
                                            target.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Erhalten: §c" + player.getName().toString() + "§8(§a+" + nf.format(Double.parseDouble(args[1])) + "§8)");
                                            return true;
                                        } else {
                                            player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Dir fehlen §8(§c" + moneyapi.getMoneyDifference(player.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1])) + "§8)");
                                            return false;
                                        }
```

[image]

Comment: How is the table in your database created?  (Please show `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for it).

Comment: why not simply round

Comment: But when you do `round` you still should not use `float`.

Comment: You must use DECIMAL datatype (with according digits amount values) in the table, not FLOAT/DOUBLE.

Comment: Hi, thnks for you really fast reactions.

CREATE TABLE `money_system` (
  `uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `money_amount` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse The double into a String. Now you split the string-double with "." in index 1. So you get the decimal places as number. Now you can parse the that into a number and must check if that number is smaller then 100.

Code:

```
//d is the double from the input
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(d).split(".")[1]);
if(decimal < 100) {
//number has 2 decimal places
} else {
//number has more then 2 decimal places
}
```

Or you can just round the number with `Math.round(d)`.